Java Regex Give All String Except those within Single Quotes
I am reaching out since I realized Java Regex is not my cup of tea. I am dealing with strings and I want to extract all strings except those within quotes.
For example,
      String myString = "IF What young > old, 'Price 1', 'Prediction One', 'Mother''s Day', good";

I tried using this regex, which works as long as there is no space between the words within the quotes.
String myRegex = "\\b(?!\\')[a-zA-Z_]+\\d*[.]?[a-zA-Z_]*\\d*(?!\\')\\b";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(myRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet();
while(m.find()){
   mySet.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println("Set: " + mySet);

This gives me:
Set: [s, young, Price, old, Prediction, IF, What, good]

But what I want is:
 Set: [young, old, IF, What, good]

The moment I try to allow spaces within the quotes using \\s+, it just refuses to work. Regex is very hard and confusing. It would be very grateful for any pointers and help!
Thank you!

"extract everything": apparently you want to ignore punctuation and spacing, and want to identify words separately. Can you clarify your definition of "everything" and of the desired output (is it a list of strings? where do the square brackets come from?) ?

Did you tried to use exclusions , i.e.: (?:[^\s,']+|\s*,\s*)   ?  maybe that would work..

Here is an analogous Python solution that is almost identical (for double quotes).

Here is a different solution based on Matcher.results:
List<String> list = Pattern.compile("'[^']*'|(\\w+)")
   .matcher(myString)
   .results()
   .filter(res -> res.group(1) != null)
   .map(res -> res.group(1))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.printf("List: %s%n", list);
//=> List: [IF, What, young, old, good]

Code Demo
This regex matches all quoted strings OR all words in a matching group.

You can technically cheese this using this regex -
\'[^\']*\'|(\w+)
Example on regex101 - https://regex101.com/r/O63ZhO/1
You will need to access your words from the matching group though
This basically matches all quotes (first) or all words, and then only words that are not in quotes end up as a part of the matching group
Change the \w+ as needed to match whatever your specific requirements are, if you need to include other special characters and such

Here is a solution based on String#split that does the job:
String myString = "IF What young > old, 'Price 1', 'Prediction One', 'Mother''s Day', good";
final List<String> myList = List.of(
   myString.split("(?:[^'\\w]*'[^']*'[^'\\w]*)+|[^'\\w]+")
);
System.out.printf("List: %s%n", myList);
//=> List: [IF, What, young, old, good]

PS: I have used List instead of Set to allow duplicate values in the result after split.
RegEx Demo
RegEx Details:
We use a regex for splitting. That regex matches 1 or more quoted string or else 1+ of any characters that are not single quote or word characters.

(?:: Start non-capture group

[^'\\w]*: Match 0+ of any characters that are not single quote or word characters
'[^']*': Match a quoted string
[^'\\w]*: Match 0+ of any characters that are not single quote or word characters


)+: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 1+ times
|: OR
[^'\\w]+: Match 1+ of any characters that are not single quote or word characters

